# Как отследить изменение массива внутри функции

Tags: javascript

у меня есть функция в которая внутри себя обновляет переменную:

```
var c = function(x, y, z){
    var data = {};
    function updateData(){
    //иногда запускает асинхронную функцию которая обновляет data
    }
    function init(){
    //Некая функция Promise
    }
    return init().then(() => {return data});
}
```

Все это возвращает мне `Promise` с массивом `data`.
Все это на странице я вызываю так:

```
let g = c('x', 'y', 'z');
    g.then(x => {
        console.log(x);
    });
```

Так вот как мне сделать так чтоб при обновлении переменной data внутри функции `c()` у меня обновлялось `x` в `then` и опять запускался `console.log(x);`

Comment: Promise - это одноразовая вещь, как только сработал resolve - второй раз ничего не придет.

Comment: в данном случае стоит посмотреть в сторону rxjs и всяких observable, либо пересмотреть архитектуру

Comment: Тоесть я не смогу вытащить обновленную дата из функции если возвращаетсья мне промис?

Comment: Смотря как именно ты обновляешь. если ты внутри `update` просто делаешь `data=...` То нет, если обновляешь по отдельным свойствам, то изменения ты можешь смотреть прям в полученном объекте.

Comment: понял спасибо!!